# Is it possible to fake referer information sent by web browsers?

Tags: referrer

My service might use referer information to tell from what web site a request is done, and I would like to make sure there is no way to fake the referer information.

Answer (score 4):

Referer can be easily spoofed.
Using a referrer is very unreliable as a method of verification.

There exists a firefox plugin called [**refspoof**](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/4513/) to do that very easily.

Even command line tools like wget have options to do that: `--referer=url`

Answer (score 3):

[It is possible](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referrer_spoofing). There's nothing you can do to prevent browsers from faking that data.

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways to fake any information sent by the client. The most basic rule of accepting information from a client is: **don't trust the client.**

Ever.

Browsers can fake, among many others, their User-Agent string and referrer (the proper spelling, the PHP function is about the most prolifically perpetuated typo going).

Comment: Actually, the original source of the typo is in the HTTP spec. Can't blame this one on PHP.

Comment: Here is a link to the HTTP spec with the typo. -- http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.36

Comment: @Asaph, seriously? I'd never really thought to check *past* PHP's typo. All those years of cursing mis-directed...gosh, do I feel silly, now. =/

Comment: Yeah... The HTTP Spec is a horrible reminder to double DOUBLE check everything before setting it in stone. Now I don't know how to spell the damn word, because I can never remember which is which!

Answer (score 1):

It's easily spoofed, so I wouldn't rely on it for anything important.

Answer (score 1):

The client is free to send you what ever data it wants. You should -never- trust what the browser sends.